# Single case - dynamic to static page using modrewrite in htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one dynamic page:

```
http://blog.mysite.com/?p=25
```

and with htaccess and modrewrite, I want to change it to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/stuff/newhome.html
```

I know it can't be that hard but this one has me stumped, any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^p=25 mysite.com/stuff/newhome.html [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Along with variations but no success.

Comment: A. p=25 has *absolutely nothing* in regard to new-link? B. What have you googled?

Comment: p=25 renders a unique page on the site whereas other numbers render different pages. It isn't a query to a page, it is the actual url to display a dynamic page. I want the link to the specific p=25 page be redirected to a new static page.

Comment: You'll need to check for `QSA`. Try googling a bit.

Comment: Looked up QSA - didn't know about it and missed it reading the docs earlier.

RewriteRule ^p=25 http://www.mysite.com/stuff/newhome.html [QSA,R=301,L]

Was tried along with variations but no success.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=25$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com/stuff/newhome.html [R=301]
```

Comment: Many thanks! This did the trick. I knew it had to be something simple. I was close a few times trying this earlier but never specifically tried "^$" in the rule. With a few additional tweaks for my specific case and all is well! - Thank you very much!